# which path needs to be a string?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Running Grunt and Sass for the first time and I am getting this error in terminal when modifying scss files:

```
danales-MacBook-Pro:sass-test danale$ grunt
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "SCSS/_main.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
Warning: Path must be a string. Received undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Completed in 0.587s at Thu Apr 20 2017 12:47:54 GMT-0400 (EDT) - Waiting...
>> File "SCSS/_mixins.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
Warning: Path must be a string. Received undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Completed in 0.545s at Thu Apr 20 2017 12:49:12 GMT-0400 (EDT) - Waiting...
```

From what I understand, the error is saying that a path in my gruntfile needs to be a string:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    /**
    * SASS
    */
    sass: {
      dev: {
      options: {
        style: 'expanded',
          sourcemap: 'none',
        },
        files: {
          'style.css': 'scss/style.css'
        }
      }
    },

    /**
    * watch
    */
    watch: {
        css: {
          files: '**/*.scss',
          tasks: ['sass']
        }
    },
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

But I am unclear as to which path needs to be a string...

Answer (score 0):

What it's saying is that the sass files you're pointing to are not there. From the `watch` output I can see that the directory is actually called `SCSS/` (versus `scss/`). Additionally, you haven't indicated what **scss** file to preprocess. Try changing your `sass` task configuration to indicate the correct directory and the main scss file:

```
files: {
    'style.css': 'SCSS/_main.scss'  // update this match your PRIMARY scss file
}
```

Comment: jakerella, I changed it to reflect what you have in your answer and I still get this error: >> File "SCSS/_main.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
Warning: Path must be a string. Received undefined Use --force to continue.

Comment: When it says that, it's almost always because the files it was looking for didn't actually exist. Double check those paths.